# Swift 2: How to discriminate between a local var and a defined function?

Tags: swift2

The following code snippet generate the error: Variable is used within is own initial value.

What notation to used to state the right namespace (such a ::now() in cpp)?

```
func now() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
}

class Issue {
    static func cleanUp() {
        let now = now()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show where you have defined `now()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `now()` is a global function, then you can create the qualified name by prefixing the name of your module:

e.g. `MyProject.now()`. The name of your module is usually the name of your project.

```
func now() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate())
}

class Issue {
    static func cleanUp() {
        let now = MyProject.now()
    }
}
```